# How to install social engineering toolkit?

Tags: software-installation

When I searched for the social engineering toolkit I got the error "no such path or file".

I used this orders for installing it but without success.

> be sure to install subversion before installing the selected tools.

(i did it)

```
svn co http://svn.secmaniac.com/social_engineering_toolkit set/
```

and the link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 16):

I wouldn't use whatever guide you are using, they moved their stuff to git several months ago:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/ set/

cd set
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Resources:

- https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/

Answer (score 4):

The URL you're using has been permanently redirected to `http://www.trustedsec.com`, which looks to me like a website, not a Subversion repository.

You'll have to contact the owner of the repository for current information about its availability.

Comment: They use git now ;).

Answer (score -1):

Download the files using

```
git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/ set/
```

Install it via

```
cd set
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Should probably be an edit to http://askubuntu.com/a/394171/158442

Comment: I think so too, probaply meant as an edit...